# Mixing future tense with present tense to describe events in the future

Tags: translation, future

I am translating a song from Russian to English. Original lyrics have a dreamy mood and shift (russian) tense from future to present, back and forth.
This is an example that I made up, not the actual lyrics I am working with:

```
We will walk in the forest,
You will be smiling at me.
Birds are singing,
Sun is shining.
You will give me a present...
```

This example demonstrates what English tenses I would have used if I had translated lines preserving the shift. I think it feels close to the "historical present", a device that is well described in numerous articles on the web, except that author adds "vividness" to the text which "base" tense is future.
Does it look like a valid stylistic choice for English text or it just confuses the reader? If the latter is true, I will play safe and just convert all the lines to future simple and future continuous. For clarification, my native language is Russian.

Comment: Since it's describing something in the future, not the past, *historical present* isn't really the right phrase. I would say *future present*, except I don't think that's a common phrase. (Maybe, technically, the third and fourth lines are in a "future relative tense." I don't actually know how this is described. That aside, I have no problem reading it as written; I prefer the poetry of the mixed tenses in this context. I've seen it employed by other people before to the same effect. But it's a matter of style, and opinions will vary.

Comment: Lyrics are normally off-topic here, because the rules governing them are relaxed to the point of POB-ness. But the A/A'/B'/B'/A construction here does seem over-jerky. I'd go with << A/You smile at me/B'/B'/You give me a present >> with an ellipsis (longer pause) at the end of the first line.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth thank you for your reply, it was not meant to show anything except the use of tenses and I did not consciously think about the rhymes. Actually I thought that the ellipsis would work similar to _Et cetera_ as there is no use in making this example any longer. Now I see that it looks like a stanza with 5 lines.

Comment: @JasonBassford Thank you for suggestions, when I googled "future present" some works on German language showed up. I like how "dramatic present" sounds, I think it could be a good umbrella term but Wikipedia tells it is only a synonym for "historical present".

Comment: My A / A' etc represent _types of temporal verb constructions_ (the term 'tense' is usually used only for 'present simple' and 'past simple' on ELU). 'The dramatic / historic / etc  present' are codings for 'the present simple used as a deliberate style choice  where a past reference might be expected'. Your question is about mixing the 'usually present addressing construction' [are/is/am + V-ing]  with the  'future addressing constructions'  [will + V] and [will be + V-ing], and I've suggested that your example chops and changes too much, and how I'd adjust it.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Oh, thanks for a thorough explanation, now I've got it. The actual Russian text that I translate has a simple four-line rhyme; as for tenses, it does not follow a visible pattern, there are just some rare inclusions of present tense here and there.

Comment: We've had a question which asked about the acceptability of mixing the historic present with more usual past constructions; the answer was that it gets ridiculous if overdone. The odd chunk in the historic present, fine.